# The Sub-Tiers of PvE Raid gear (MoP)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have noticed that there are 5 'Sub-Tiers' for the gear dropped in Raids:

1. ***Heroic Warforged*** - iLvl 572 (Max 588) [Upgrade: +6]
2. ***Heroic*** - iLvl 566 (Max 582) [Upgrade: +7]
3. ***Warforged*** - iLvl 559 (Max 575) [Upgrade: +6]
4. ***Normal*** - iLvl 553 (Max 569) [Upgrade: +13]
5. ***Flexible*** - iLvl 540 (Max 556) [Upgrade: +12]
6. ***LFR*** - iLvl 528 (Max 544)

I Understand that *LFR* drops from *LFR Raids*, *Flexible* from *Flex Raids*, *Normal* from *Normal Raids* and *Heroic* from *Heroic Raids*.

I have noticed that *Warforged* gives +6 item Level.

What I do not understand, is how to get the *Warforged* items? Do you have to manually do something to upgrade them? Are there special conditions under which you could loot these?

Also, can you get the *Set Pieces* (Head, Shoulders, Gloves, Legs, Chest) as a *Warforged* item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the wowwiki page:](http://www.wowwiki.com/Warforged)

> Warforged (and "Heroic Warforged") is a new sub-type of raid item drop
>   quality introduced with Patch 5.4 in the Siege of Orgrimmar raid
>   similar to the Thunderforged and Heroic Thunderforged items. Each
>   Patch 5.4 raid boss will have a chance of dropping this new
>   designation of a particular item that's 6 item levels higher than
>   their Normal or Heroic mode counterparts.

[Also see the wowpedia page:](http://wowpedia.org/Warforged)

> Warforged items are upgrades of non-Tier 16 items that have a slim
>   chance to drop from Normal and Heroic mode boss encounters in Siege of
>   Orgrimmar or in world boss Ordos. The Warforged designation awards an
>   additional six item levels to an item — where a normal mode item has
>   an item level of 553, a Warforged normal item is item level 559. The
>   same applies for Heroic items: regular Heroic items are item level
>   566, whereas Heroic Warforged items are item level 572. While drop
>   rates for Warforged items are rare, they will be slightly more common
>   in 25-player modes as compared to 10-player modes. Additionally, using
>   a  [Warforged Seal](http://wowpedia.org/Warforged_Seal) (the Patch 5.4.0 equivalent of an  [Elder Charm of
>   Good Fortune] or  [Mogu Rune of Fate]) will afford a chance to receive
>   a Warforged item.

So to answer your questions:

Q. What I do not understand, is how to get the Warforged items?
 A. It's a chance on any non-tier drop from a siege of ogrimmar raid boss.

Q. Also, can you get the Set Pieces (Head, Shoulders, Gloves, Legs, Chest) as a Warforged item?
 A. No, only non-tier items can roll into a warforged version.

Comment: So this is a *random* drop per boss, *only one*, and gets rolled on by the entire raid group? Kind of like the Seals/Tokens were in WotLK?

Comment: @HowlinWulf: Any piece of gear that drops has a chance to be Warforged. In theory, you could see all of a boss's drops be Warforged. The item can then be distributed as normal, unless it came from a bonus roll in which case it is limited to the person who rolled it